# Resend HTTP post before error timeout

Tags: javascript, angular, http, typescript, post

I have an Angular 4 project that uses a http post to commands across to our backend. The issue is that sometimes a command can be sent out before the backend is fully up and running. Normally an "ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT" would occur, but our embedded browser for whatever reason holds onto the post for an extremely long time before giving us the error (5 minutes). Since a 5 minute wait is unacceptable, I need to come up with a way to re-send our http post if there isn't a response within 15-30~ seconds

Here is what the current post looks like

```
this._http.post(this.sockclientURL, body, { headers: headers })
  .subscribe((res) => {

    let text = res.text();

    if (text.startsWith("ERROR")) {
      console.log("Sockclient Error.");
      if (this.sockclientErrorRetryCount < this.sockclientErrorRetryLimit) {
        console.log("Retrying in 3 seconds.");
        this.sockclientErrorRetryCount++;

        setTimeout(() => {
          this.SendCommand(command, success, fail);
        }, 3000);
      }
      return;
    }
    else {
      this.sockclientErrorRetryCount = 0;
    }

    if (text == "N" || text.startsWith("N ")) {
      this._modalService.alert(this._nackLookup.convert(text));
      if (typeof fail == 'function') {
        fail(text);
      }
    }
    else {

      let deserializedCommand = command.deserialize(text);

      success(deserializedCommand);

      let repeatMillis: number = deserializedCommand.getRepeatMillis();

      if (repeatMillis && repeatMillis > 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.SendCommand(command, success, fail);
        }, repeatMillis);
      }
    }
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    let repeatMillis = 1000;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.SendCommand(command, success, fail);
      }, repeatMillis);
  });
```

So to re-cap, I have some code in place to re-attempt the command if an error occurs, but our embedded browser holds onto its timeout error for several minutes. I need something to attempt to re-send after 15-30 seconds of no response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retries are immediately executed without waiting for a delay. A better one consists of waiting for a bit before retrying and abort after a given amount of time. Observables allow to mix retryWhen, delay and timeout operators to achieve this, as described in the following snippet:

```
this._http.post(this.sockclientURL, body, { headers: headers })
 .retryWhen(error => error.delay(500))
 .timeout(2000, new Error('delay exceeded'))
 .map(res => res.map());
```

Comment: I am getting:
 Argument of type 'Error' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IScheduler'.
  Property 'now' is missing in type 'Error'. on the new error

Comment: Looks like they fixed it .timeoutWith(2000, Observable.throw(new Error('delay exceeded')))

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure it still works in Angular4, but you *should* be able to do:

```
this
  ._http
  .post(this.sockclientURL, body, { headers: headers })
  .timeout(15000, new Error('timeout exceeded')) // or 30000
  .subscribe((res) => { /* ... */ })
```

Comment: I'm getting Argument of type 'Error' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IScheduler'.
  Property 'now' is missing in type 'Error'.

Comment: Looks like we use .timeoutWith(2000, Observable.throw(new Error('delay exceeded')))

Answer (score 0):

A little more information would be needed as to the entire scope of the application, however when I get myself in to situations like this I normally look at the following avenues of approach:

1. Will a try / catch solve my problem. 
       In your catch, you could redirect elsewhere. If you don't catch anything 
       often times you will get a bit of lag.
2. Is there a way to avoid the error all together through user constraints.

Lastly, You may want to use setInterval() over setTimeout().

Can you provide more information as to the scope of the operation?